# Why does my app crash when a button is clicked?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make a friends function into my Unity game. Each friend will have their own line with their name and a few buttons (challenge, about, etc.).
I have a friend row prefab and I instantiate it into the parent list for each friend.
It works just fine, until I click the  challenge button, which whould call a method that takes in two parameters: the UId of the friend, and their username (two strings).
I am using Firebase Realtime Database for database.

```
void RetrieveFriendList(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args) {
    foreach(Transform childTransform in listParent.GetComponentInChildren<Transform>()) {
        GameObject.Destroy(childTransform.gameObject);
    }
    friends.Clear();
    foreach (DataSnapshot s in args.Snapshot.Children) {
        friends.Add(s.Key);
        GameObject newRow = Instantiate(friendRowPrefab);
        newRow.transform.Find("Deny").gameObject.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        newRow.transform.Find("Challenge").gameObject.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        newRow.transform.SetParent(listParent.transform);
        newRow.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f);
        newRow.transform.Find("Text_Name").gameObject.GetComponent<TMPro.TMP_Text>().text = s.Child("username").Value.ToString();
        string retrievedStatus = s.Child("type").Value.ToString();
        if (retrievedStatus == "sent") {
            newRow.transform.Find("Status").gameObject.GetComponent<TMPro.TMP_Text>().text = "Friend request sent";
        } else if (retrievedStatus == "request") {
            newRow.transform.Find("Status").gameObject.GetComponent<TMPro.TMP_Text>().text = "Incoming friend request";
            newRow.transform.Find("Accept").gameObject.SetActive(true);
            newRow.transform.Find("Deny").gameObject.SetActive(true);
            newRow.transform.Find("Accept").gameObject.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate { AcceptFriendRequest(s.Key); });
            newRow.transform.Find("Deny").gameObject.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate { DenyFriendRequest(s.Key); });
        } else if (retrievedStatus == "friends") {
            newRow.transform.Find("Challenge").gameObject.SetActive(true);
            Debug.Log(s.Key + " - " + s.Child("username").Value.ToString());

            newRow.transform.Find("Challenge").gameObject.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate { ChallengeFriend(s.Key, s.Child("username").Value.ToString()); }); //this is the line that causes the crash

            newRow.transform.Find("About").gameObject.SetActive(true);
            newRow.transform.Find("Status").gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("users").Child(auth.CurrentUser.UserId).Child("friends").ValueChanged -= RetrieveFriendList;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger to step through this code: on what line does the error occur? Any exception details?

Comment: The app and unity crashes when I try to pass the snapshot key and it's child's value to the ChallengeFriend method. I do not get any exceptions, it just crashes

Comment: Just some general notes: `listParent.GetComponentInChildren<Transform>()` basically equals `listParent.transform` instead of all these `Find` calls I would strongly recommend to rather have one central controller script on the root of your prefab you Instantiate and store all required references already via the Inspector and then just let it handle the entire initialization .. this would make your code way better to read and maintain

Comment: @derHugo Thanks for the suggestion. How can I handle the initialization on the prefab's controller? I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I'm pretty beginner, but I would like to make my code better

Comment: Have one component e.g `public class RowController : MonoBehaviour` that goes on the root of your prefab. Then for each of the things you need later have a field like e.g. `public Button deny button;` etc .. then you make your prefab of according type `public RowController friendRowPrefab;` and this way right after instantiating it you simply do `var newRow = Instantiate (friendRowPrefab); newRow.denyButton.onclick....` instead of all `Find` and `GetComponent` calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's likely happening is that the underlying C++ representation of your database snapshot is being cleaned up *before* your button accesses it. See [this bug](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/635).

The easiest thing to do would be to find this line:

```
newRow.transform.Find("Challenge").gameObject.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate { ChallengeFriend(s.Key, s.Child("username").Value.ToString()); }); //this is the line that causes the crash
```

and turn it into something like:

```
var challengeKey = s.Key;
var challengeUsername = s.Child("username").Value.ToString();
newRow.transform.Find("Challenge").gameObject.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate { ChallengeFriend(challengeKey, challengeUsername); });
```

This way you retrieve the values you need (key and username) at the time of the callback rather than in the context of the button click (at some arbitrary point in the future after this function has returned). If you still get a crash, you may have to `.Clone` or `.CopyTo` the data -- but I believe that once an object is retrieved from the underlying snapshot it should be a full on C# object obeying the expected C# GC rules.

You also may experience null reference exceptions if the snapshot hits a local cache first -- so make sure you have null checks around everything (generally a good practice whenever you're hitting the web).